# different css on same element by id, class etc

Tags: html, css

There is one `<p>` tag with class `.eleclass` and id `#eleid` and i have specified 3 css to the `<p>` tag one specified with class second with id and third with just p declared.

```css
p#eleid{
  color:yellow;
}
p.eleclass{
  color:blue;
}
p{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<p id="eleid" class="eleclass">
hello para.
</p>
```

Now i wonder why the rule applied to `p#eleid` is working when css runs from top to bottom nature and at bottom color red is specified so `<p>` should be red in color.

Is there any css rules hidden behind it??

> This problem inclues use of id not only class.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Because of id. Id always have high priority. For more [read](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-specificity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes down to **CSS specificity**.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied.

As it happens, an ID based selector has higher priority than a tag based selector. This is because an ID is more *specific* than a tag. In other words, the tag selector applies to all p elements, while the ID will only apply to the p *with the ID*.

There are ways around specificity, such as the [`!important`](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/important-declarations/) keyword - however, I mostly recommend **against** working around specificity, as it can lead to bugs.